# Rails Form Helpers Problem with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following two lines of code in one of my views (index action in ProjectController ) The below code is inside a loop that loops over @projects instance variable as `project`.

```
    <td><%= link_to(project.name, :action => 'show', :id => project.id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to("Edit", :action => 'edit', :id => project.id ) %></td>
```

The first helper gives me this link:
             `http://localhost:3000/project/show/1` etc whereas the second helper outputs: `http://localhost:3000/project/edit?id=1` etc I would like both the links to follow the same conventions. Ie. the one preferred by Rails (the first one)

Here's my controller methods:

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.find(:all)
  end

  def new
    @project = project.new
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Certain actions not shown for brevity..

**UPDATE:** I get the same link with ? if i use:

```
 <td><%= link_to(project.type, :action => 'edit', :id => project.id ) %></td>
```

where `type` is one of the other column in the projects table in my database.

Comment: Can you post your routes please?

Comment: Thanks! there was a problem in my `routes.rb` file, it had an entry as folllows: `get "project/edit"

Comment: Can you though explain why this line prevented Rails from acting the way i expected it to be...? Just curious

Comment: You would be better to post your findings as an answer in order to help the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you declare your resource in `routes.rb`:

```
map.resources :posts
```

Then in console run `rake routes` so you can see all your route.

Here are the links you need for that resource. I will put edit first because that is what you need help with and remember to surround all these links with embedded ruby tags `<%= %>`

```
@post.each do |post|  
  link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post)
  link_to "Destroy", post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?"
  link_to "Show", post
  link_to "New Post", new_post_path
end
```

Those should be all the links you need for that resource

## Update

If you not using REST which you should because it makes things easier in the long run and rails is wonderfully a REST API you could just make a named route for edit. Otherwise you could add this to format your routes but these types of routes are not secure:

```
map.connect ':controller/:id/:action'
```

add that to `routes.rb` and it will give you a non-RESTful Rails app with REST like views :)

Comment: thanks Sam, but as i just mentioned, i wasn't using resource routing yet.

Comment: It's silly not to. It's more conceptually but less code wise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get different results with the same syntax but neither of them seem to be correct and I think the reason is that the :id arguments is not passed on when link_to uses url_for to create the path.

I think that you can use either one of these examples assuming that you use resources :projects in your routes.rb:

```
<td><%= link_to(project.name, { :action => 'show', :id => project.id } ) %></td>
<td><%= link_to("Edit", { :action => 'edit', :id => project.id } ) %></td>
```

or:

```
<td><%= link_to(project.name, project_path(project.id) ) %></td>
<td><%= link_to("Edit", edit_project_path(project.id) ) %></td>
```

Comment: currently i'm not using the resource routing in rails 3.0, although i am using Rails 3.0, but i wanted to stick to catch-all routing for actions in the development mode. Will shift to resource routes once i'm close to deployment...

Answer (score 0):

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  get "project/index"

  get "project/new"

  get "project/create"

  get "project/update"

  get "project/delete"

  get "project/destroy"

  get "project/edit" <---- Notice this line

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

The problem was somehow created by the Routes.rb file. I had a catch-all routes line for my routes at the bottom of my routes.rb file - this is something which is now deprecated in Rails 3.0 and Rails 3.0 now encourages resource routing.

When i generated my Project Controller, it added these get lines into the routes file. these get lines correspond to the actions that i defined when i generated the controller through the console. Whereas the `show` action was generated manually, and hence fell back to the last line.

Comment: Just FYI, if you are going to build your application around these routes and then shift to correct routing later, you are basically going to have to remake half your application... The routing is so fundamental in MVC apps

Comment: Thanks Danne! Will take that into consideration and try to implement Resource Routing as i go..